# How can i get Application_UnhandledException details in silverlight/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, silverlight-5.0

```
 private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { ReportErrorToDOM(e); });
        }
    }
```

I have a solution with a silverlight application (that calls a webservice) being hosted in an asp.net application.

If there is any unhanded exception in the application, i want to get as much detail as can be possible e.g the exception message, innerexception details, file where exception occurred, method which was being called.....just like what i would get in a catch block.

So from the Application_UnhandledException event above, how can i get this information from the  ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.ExceptionObject.ToString()
```

is better than the default from the wizard in that it also gives you nested exception names, messages and stack traces.

Method names are included in the stack traces.

File names and line numbers, however, are not retrievable from Silverlight by any method I know of, even when running with elevated privileges.